# Adding CKEditor content to a database

Tags: ckeditor

Please help me. I have been assigned to input data in the CKEditor demo and store that input in a database. What is the code for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, or what you have researched, that would better help us help you.

Comment: That's just it. I'm not sure what to try. Should I try JQuery to insert the CKEditor content? Should I use my own instance of CKEditor?

Answer (score 1):

The question you are asking is very broad. There are a multitude  of different ways to go about accomplishing your goal. The scope of answers we can provide vary greatly depending on your experience. I would recommend visiting W3 schools to get you started. 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Start off by making a new database, or connecting to an existing one. Then you can start by installing CKE and we can go from there.

This site is designed to answer specific questions, for example we would be more than happy to help if you hit a road block while trying to design or build a database. We do ask however, that you please provide us with what you know, and what you have tried and experienced problems with. Doing so not only makes it easier for us to answer, but helps beginners get in the proper mindset for development and makes it much easier to learn. There is an overwhelming amount of tutorials you can find via google to get you started. We will be more than happy to help once you come back with a more centered question.

Comment: I have now been able to successfully design a CKEditor control into my webpage. I can use the CKEditor to add text to a database. However, now I need  to know how to upload an image. I'm told I need to make a new .ashx file and put in some code. However, whenever I try to access my .ashx file, I come up with a .ashx.cs file instead. Any ideas? P.S. The reason I'm not including .ashx code is because it contains too many characters for commenting.

Comment: Correction: The .ashx.cs file already has all the proper code.

Comment: Just to clarify, I added the CKEditor control by doing the following 3 things: I downloaded CKEditor full version and CKEditor for asp.net. A added a reference to CKEditor.dll in my main directory, and I copied the contents of[link] (www.youtube.com)CKEditor to the main directory.